# Sed: select first part of price

Tags: regex, linux, bash, macos, sed

Seems that my `sed` command is not working. I am trying to select the 2 in $2.99. However, no matter how I seem to type the  `regex`, it will only give the .99
I want to select everything (every number) that is not the dollar sign up to the period.
Any suggestions?

`echo "$2.99" | sed -e 's:^\([^\\$]*\).:the price is \1.:'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with your `sed` but with `echo`. Note that `$2` when expanded under double quotes is the positional parameter two which expands nothing in this case. So in essence you're doing

```
echo ".99" | something
```

The right approach would be

```
echo '$2.99' | sed -E 's/\$([[:digit:]]*)\..*$/The price is Dollar \1/'
#Note that $2 inside single quotes is literal $2
```

Output

```
The price is Dollar 2
```

---

<sup>**Note :** The `\1` in the substitution part expands to the matched part inside the parenthesis.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I did notice the double quotes as a problem before you posted your answer, but now that I see what you did, I can see where I went wrong. You made the expression in full and used the capturing group to select the 2.